# click on element in webpage if it's exist by webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I skip some notification with this code.But when notification don't display this line code makes error.

```
'''
driver.find_element_by_class_name('aOOlW.HoLwm').click
'''
```

How can I use this code only when that element display??

Comment: try to check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use like this:

```
element_selector = 'aOOlW.HoLwm'

def check_exists_by(selector, by=By.CLASS_NAME):
    try:
        driver.find_element(by, selector)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True

if check_exists_by(element_selector):
   driver.find_element_by_class_name(element_selector).click()
```

of course, you should import all of the modules:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

and it work if you have correct selector

if you want to check is displayed, not only present in dom, there's opportunity to add is_displayd flag:

```
def check_exists_by(selector, by=By.CLASS_NAME, is_displayed=True):
    try:
        el = driver.find_element(by, selector)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    if is_displayed:
       return el.is_displayed()
    return True
```